# Inputting a file address from a .text file to OpenSSL encryption function in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, aes

I want to direct multiple lines of output from a .txt file to that encrypt() function. The .txt file contains addresses of files I want to encrypt. The code compiles but no encryption pans out. I am using EVP_aes_256_cbc() for encryption. What am I doing wrong?

```
int encrypt(unsigned char* plaintext, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext);
int decrypt(unsigned char* ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, unsigned char* key, unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* plaintext);


int main() {
    unsigned char key[16];
    RAND_bytes(key, sizeof(key));

    unsigned char iv[16];
    RAND_bytes(iv, sizeof(iv));

    std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\NULL\source\repos\xFolder\YFolder\\test.txt");
    std::string str;
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        int encrypt(unsigned char* str, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key,unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext);
    }
```

Comment: Apart from the errors pointed out in Mike's answer, `encrypt` and `decrypt` looks wrong. Fixed: `int encrypt(const unsigned char* plaintext, int plaintext_len, const unsigned char* key, const unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext);` and `int decrypt(const unsigned char* ciphertext, int ciphertext_len, const unsigned char* key, const unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* plaintext);`

Comment: @Ted Thank you for the input but with your suggestions my code does not compile, Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl encrypt(unsigned char const *,int,unsigned char const *,unsigned char const *,unsigned char *)" (?encrypt@@YAHPEBEH00PEAE@Z)

Comment: Aren't those functions you've defined yourself or copied from the C example at the OpenSSL homepage?

Comment: Ted I did not copy from OpenSSL page. Thank you, you have been very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome! The function signatures look very similar to the examples at the [OpenSSL wiki](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption) and probably have the same problem (not properly `const` where it should be) so I guess you can change both the declaration and the definition (unless they are defined somewhere where you can't change it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++, `\` is used in escape sequences, so you have to write `\\` to express `\` in string literals.

You actually did this for the first and last `\`, but you have to do this for the other `\`s.

```
    std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\NULL\source\repos\xFolder\YFolder\\test.txt");
```

should be

```
    std::ifstream file("C:\\Users\\NULL\\source\\repos\\xFolder\\YFolder\\test.txt");
```

Also in this loop

```
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        int encrypt(unsigned char* str, int plaintext_len, unsigned char* key,unsigned char* iv, unsigned char* ciphertext);
    }
```

You didn't call the function but instead of that you only declared that.

You should call the function to do encryption. It may be like this:

```
    while (std::getline(file, str))
    {
        std::vector<unsigned char> encrypted_str(str.size()); // you may need some more bytes
        encrypt(reinterpret_cast<unsigned char*>(str.data()), str.size(), key, iv, &encrypted_str[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Alternatives: `R"aw(C:\Users\NULL\source\repos\xFolder\YFolder\test.txt)aw"` or `"C:/Users/NULL/source/repos/xFolder/YFolder/test.txt"`

Comment: Thank you Mike for replying
MSVS 2019 it gives me this error after correcting the problems you suggested.

error C2440: 'static_cast': cannot convert from '_Elem *' to 'unsigned char *'
1>        with
1>        [
1>            _Elem=char
1>        ]

Comment: ```
Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```